# ios.googleAdUnitId bottom banner doesn't show on iPhone 6 and 6+ in landscape mode

Tags: iphone, ipad, codenameone, landscape-portrait, banner-ads

I'm using ios.googleAdUnitId build hint to make the app showing the ads at bottom banner in Codename One. In portrait orientation, the ads is shown on all my iPad Mini, iPhone 6 and iPhone 6+ devices. However, in landscape orientation, the ads is only shown on iPad Mini. It is not shown on iPhone 6 and iPhone 6+. Any advice? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The layout uses padding at the bottom of the form to reserve space for the ad. However, if the layout takes up all the space the padding won't have space left and would effectively disappear.

You have 2 possible solutions I can see:

1. Fix the layout so it will shrink easily (e.g. make the content scrollable on the Y axis).
2. Lock the application to portrait only on iOS (you can do that from the iOS section in the preferences).

Comment: I think it has space because a white bar is shown and my app is shrinked up but I don't know why the ads is not shown inside that white bar. I see there is the ios.googleAdUnitIdPadding build hint. What is its unit? can you give some sample please?

Comment: If you see the spacing reserved to the ad but not the ad there might be a different problem involved. I think this might be an issue that required fixes from the native layer. Please file an issue on that, but I'm not sure when we'll get around to fix it as most developers have already switched to full screen ads from the cn1lib's.

Comment: Thanks Shai. How can I file an issue for this?

Comment: The git issue tracker see https://www.codenameone.com/blog/issue-submission-guideline.html

Comment: I have the same issue on an iPhone 6s: a blanc space at the bottom of the screen all the time, and no ad showing, and no error message. I couldn't find an issue in Github, was it ever resolved (or did William figure out how to fix it)?

Comment: I don't know. I think we made some changes to google play services with iOS but I don't think we addressed this particular issue. I'm not sure we'll be able to resolve it soon since October is mostly holidays around here and the guy working on this is on vacation. I suggest filing an issue on this and I'll assign it then pinging us about it early November